# Detect Redirect Loop in nginx because Browser Caching of 301 and HSTS

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, dns, browser-cache, http-status-code-301

In our current site all our http traffic is redirected to https using permanent redirects(301).

Now I want to redirect all https traffic to http and for some pages(like checkout, login) it will be http to https

I have done the configurations in nginx, and they work fine (tested with adding entry to /etc/hosts) only when browser cache is cleaned.

Since browser caches all the redirects and it is not possible to tell users to clean browser cache, I am exploring of ways to do this project.

What is happening is when I hit http version it gets redirected to https version due to browser caching. Since, in my configuration I have redirected to http version, the request gets redirected to http and redirections enter infinite loop.

The ways I can think of are:

1. Some how nginx detects that there is a second time request to https and serves him https content insted of redirecting to http. I know this is against the principle of http, but I was wondering if it is possible. Please let me know if it is possible this way. I will be serving both https and http to a browser but when cache is cleared eventually it will work fine with no further changes required.
2. If I change A record of DNS, will it cause the browser cache to be clean. If that happens I will go for it.
3. I keep both http and https versions for a while with no redirects and after one month or so, do the redirections.

Comment: Why not use HTTPS everywhere?

Comment: For slight performance gain, but really I don't know. It's how every ecommerce company is doing. So that's the reason

Comment: there is no absoluely performance reason at all. You rather expose secure cookies while redirect from login page to dashboard, this is security anti pattern nowadays.

Comment: check this out with modern browser that supports HTTP/2 http://www.httpvshttps.com

Comment: is it possible to move the secure pages to new addresses? i.e., instead of everything flowing thru www.example.com, keep www but send checkout to secure.example.com? This would **greatly** simply the process and allow you to test everything ahead of time.